# spring circular dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);
    @Resource
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Resource
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    .....

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class MobileApiSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Resource
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        @Resource
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        @Autowired
        private CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter customBasicAuthenticationFilter;
        @Autowired
        private TokenSecurityFilter tokenSecurityFilter;

        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .addFilter(customBasicAuthenticationFilter)
                .addFilterBefore(tokenSecurityFilter, CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()           
                    .antMatchers(Mappings.MOBILE_API + "/**").hasAnyRole(Globals.MOBILE_API_USER_ROLE)
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .requestCache()
                    .requestCache(new NullRequestCache());
        }

    }
```

This is my custom filter:

```
@Component
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    @Autowired
    private PrincipalRepository principalRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationCache authenticationCache;

    @Autowired
    public CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
       super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException {
        Principal principal = principalRepository.findOne(PrincipalPredicates.userNameEquals(authResult.getName()));

        if (principal != null) {
            principal.setLastLoginTime(DateTime.now());
            principalRepository.save(principal);
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to retrieve user " + authResult.getName());
        }

        authenticationCache.add(authResult, request, response);

        super.onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
    }
}
```

But, when trying to deploy to Tomcat, the following exception is thrown:

```
Error creating bean with name 'customBasicAuthenticationFilter' defined in file [C:\work\...]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I am not sure why my filter is looking for an authenticationManager since I am autowiring it. Help is appreciated it.

**Updated Question:  I added this code to resolve the authenticationManager issue**:

```
@Bean(name="myAuthenticationManager")
           @Override
           public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
               return super.authenticationManagerBean();
           }
```

By adding the above, I am able to get past the authenticationManager issue, but now I am getting this issue:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Could not autowire field: private CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter SecurityConfig$MobileApiSecurityConfigurerAdapter.customBasicAuthenticationFilter; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'customBasicAuthenticationFilter':
 Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Thanks

Comment: You auto wired the bean with the constructor.  Where do you tell the bean factory how to create the AuthenticationManager instance to pass to the constructor?  That's what it's complaining about.  Auto wiring the constructor dependency isn't sufficient; you have to create the bean to reference, too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I think I understand the issue, but I am just not sure how to fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation on top of `MobileApiSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I added the @Lazy annotation to the filter and I'm able to deploy now.

Feel free to offer other solutions.